# Does a "SELECT * FROM (SELECT ..." create a temporary table?

Tags: sql-server

Does doing a

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT foo.id, bar.name FROM foo LEFT JOIN bar ON bar.foo_id = foo.id)
              \--------------- Will this be a temp table? --------------------------/
```

create the same type of temporary table as declaring a table with # does in a stored procedure? Or does it create a view or perhaps some other magic?
A quick search on temporary tables only showed them being used in stored procedures.

Comment: Maybe. How does it help you if it does? How does it help you if it doesn't?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliver: I have quite a large query that uses this and wanted to understand what happens under the hood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it does yes, but internally only.

you wouldn't have access to it after the whole query is executed.

Answer (score 1):

Temp table will be created in memory then as said, lost. For complex sub queries this will obviously put some strain on memory, but as with most things, memory is faster than disk.

You could do nested queries as individual ones, using a temp table (on disk) to then perform another query, eventually dropping the table.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, the outer query does nothing.  So the query optimizer will optimize it away.

You can see the flow of result sets in the query execution plan.  For example, a `loop join` results in a temporary structure that contains the resulting rows.  The temporary structure could be stored in tempdb much like a temporary table is.  But it won't be visible to you, and it will be deallocated after the query completes.

Comment: The actual query is a bit more complex and actually does a lot more so it was perhaps dumb to use such a simple query that will be optimized like that :). I just wanted to know if the part within parentheses would be handled as a temporary table.

Comment: One way to tell is to examine the query execution plan.  Some subqueries can be executed row-by-row.  Those do not require any temporary storage.